# Can kernel code make things read-only in a way that other kernel code can't undo?

Tags: security, assembly, linux-kernel, x86-64, page-tables

I'm under the impression that the Linux kernel's attempts to protect itself revolve around not letting malicious code run in kernelspace. In particular, if a malicious kernel module were to get loaded, that it would be "game over" from a security standpoint. However, I recently came across [a post](https://old.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/g5y3vw/linux_kernel_lockdown_integrity_and/fo9vjgm/) that contradicts this belief and says that there is some way that the kernel can protect parts of itself from other parts of itself:

> There is plenty of mechanisms to protect you against malicious modules. I write kernel code for fun so I have some experience in the field; it's basically a flag in the pagetable.
>
> > What's there to stop any kernel module from changing that flag in the pagetable back? The only protection against malicious modules is keeping them from loading at all. Once one loads, it's game over.
> >
> > > Make the pagetable readonly. Done.
> > >
> > > > Kernel modules can just make it read-write again, the same way your code made it read-only, then carry on with their changes.
> > > >
> > > > > You can actually lock this down so that kernel mode cannot modify the page table until an interrupt occurs. If your IDT is read-only as well there is no way for the module to do anything about it.

That doesn't make any sense to me. Am I missing something big about how kernel memory works? Can kernelspace code restrict itself from modifying the page table? Would that really prevent kernel rootkits? If so, then why doesn't the Linux kernel do that today to put an end to all kernel rootkits?

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/Paging#Page_Directory Well, kernel has completely control over the software, but there are __hardware__ restrictions that still apply. So, if there is a method that configures the MMU to disable write access to memory...

Comment: @KamilCuk But do any of the hardware restrictions actually let the kernel lock itself out? In particular, won't CR0's WP bit always be changeable by the kernel, and then all other write-protection is off for it?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Good point. Done.

Comment: *why doesn't the Linux kernel do that today* - probably because it might need to modify page tables before the next interrupt happens.  e.g. for an mmap system call.  I'm not sure what mechanism the person had in mind for that "locking down".  Surely not lowering privilege to ring 1 or 2 to stop itself from running a [`mov cr3, reg64`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov-1) and installing a new top-level page table.  Stopping a wild memory-overwrite bug from modifying memory that happens to hold page tables could be helpful if there's a way to do that, though.

Comment: I'd suggest asking user zaarn directly what they have in mind, or ideally, if they can share an example.

Comment: @NateEldredge [I did](https://old.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/g5y3vw/linux_kernel_lockdown_integrity_and/focnf9r/). He didn't answer. (It looks like he saw my post and downvoted it, so I don't expect an answer to be forthcoming.)

Comment: There's a technique that looks vaguely related described in [this paper](https://www.ndss-symposium.org/ndss2011/practical-protection-of-kernel-integrity-for-commodity-os-from-untrusted-extensions/): "Practical Protection of Kernel Integrity for Commodity OS from Untrusted Extensions" by X. Xiong, D. Tian, P. Liu, NDSS Symposium 2011.  But their approach looks considerably more complicated and uses hypervisor features.

Comment: Anyway, it seems to me that you are assuming that a rootkit necessarily *neeeds* to make some kind of `RO->RW->MODIFY->RO` operation in order to install itself. If you allow loading modules, you are done, you don't really need a way to "unprotect" RO memory to be effective. A rootkit could just install a new `ioctl()` that escalates whichever process calls it, it could modify the bootloader to be loaded on the next boot, or it could could even just tamper with files on the disk. Even assuming HW based RO memory protection, there would still be room for rootkits.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Yeah, rootkits are a bit broad. I'm really just asking about overwriting kernel memory, and setting aside other things rootkits could do.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica yeah I was just answering your last two questions. So you're only left with the first two, which are the most important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the malicious kernel code is loaded in the trusted way (e.g. loading a kernel module and not exploiting a vulnerability) then **no**: kernel code is kernel code.

Intel CPUs do have a series of mechanisms to disable read/write access to kernel memory:

- `CR0.WP` if set disallows writes accesses to both user and kernel read-only pages. Used to detect bugs in the kernel code.
- `CR4.PKE` if set (4-level paging must be enabled, mandatory in 64-bit mode) disallows the kernel from accessing (not including instruction fetches) the user page mode unless these are tagged with the right key (which marks their RW permissions). Used to allow the kernel to write to structures like VSDO and `KUSER_SHARED_DATA` but not other user mode structures. The keys permissions are in an MSR, not in memory; the keys themselves are in the page table entries.
- `CR4.SMEP` if set disallows kernel instruction fetching from user mode pages. Used to prevent attacks where a kernel function pointer is redirected to a user mode allocated page (e.g. the `nelson.c` privilege escalation exploit).
- `CR4.SMAP` if set disallows kernel access to user mode pages during *implicit* access or during any type (implicit or explicit) of access (if `EFLAGS.AC=0`, thus overriding the protection keys). Used to enforce a more strictly no-user-mode-access policy.
- Of course the `R/W` and `U/S` bits in the paging structures control if the item is read-only/read-write and assigned to user or kernel.

You can read how permissions are applied for **supervisor-mode accesses** in the Intel manual:

> Data writes to supervisor-mode addresses.
>   Access rights depend on the value of CR0.WP:
>   - **If CR0.WP = 0, data may be written to any supervisor-mode address.**
>   - If CR0.WP = 1, data may be written to any supervisor-mode address with a translation for which the
>   R/W flag (bit 1) is 1 in every paging-structure entry controlling the translation; data may not be written
>   to any supervisor-mode address with a translation for which the R/W flag is 0 in any paging-structure
>   entry controlling the translation.

So even if the kernel protected a page `X` as read-only and then protected the page structures themselves as read-only, a malicious module could simply clear `CR0.WP`.
It could also change `CR3` and use its own paging structures.

Note that Intel developed *SGX* to address the threat model where the kernel itself is evil.
However, running the kernel components into enclaves in a secure way (i.e. no single point of failure) may not be trivial.

Another approach is virtualizing the kernel with the *VMX* extension, though this is by no way trivial to implement.

Finally, the CPU has four protection levels at the segmentation layer but paging has only two: supervisor (CPL = 0) and user (CPL > 0).
It is theoretically possible to run a kernel component in "Ring 1" but then you'd need to make an interface (e.g. something like a call gate or `syscall`) for it to access the other kernel functions.
It's easier to run it in user mode altogether (since you don't trust the module in the first place).

I have no idea what this is supposed to mean:

> You can actually lock this down so that kernel mode cannot modify the page table until an interrupt occurs.

I don't recall any mechanism by which the interrupt handling will lock/unlock anything.
I'm curious though, if anybody can shed some light they are welcome.

Security in the x86 CPUs (but this may be generalized) has always been *hierarchical*: whoever cames first set up the constraints for whoever cames later.
There is usually little to no protection between nonisolated components at the same hierarchical level.

Comment: When you say "fetch" you mean *code* fetch, right?  (As opposed to fetching data from memory).  Unfortunately "fetch" doesn't unambiguously mean "code fetch"; I don't think there is a one-word technical term so I'd recommend saying "code fetch".

Comment: My only thought with "locking down" until the next interrupt was some kind of dropping privilege, which would be restored by the CPU entering an interrupt handler in ring 0.  But I don't know of any way other than switching to ring 1 or 2 if that would be meaningful, and IDK if it would even be helpful.  And not something you want to do in a monolithic kernel like Linux where you might discover a need to change page tables with no interrupt (e.g. an mmap syscall)

Comment: @PeterCordes Good point, I'll change the wording. Regarding the lockdown, the user seems to imply it's something easy. One could drop the privileges but then you must be careful about what is allowed to be called. In the end, you'd just create another "user mode" land.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too.  Although even if there was some way to drop only write privilege for some parts of kernel memory, you'd still end up with some kind of microkernel (having another kind of user-land as you say) if there were parts of the kernel that needed to be more trusted to actually do such writes.